# Create object recursive

Tags: django

How i can create object recursive on Django..

This is my code:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
description = request.POST.get('description')
category = request.POST.get('category')
category = Category(
   name = nombre,
   name = descripcion,
   parent = category
)
category.save()
```

this code return error:

> Cannot assign "1L": "Category.parent" must be a "Category" instance.

Please some one suggest..thanks

Comment: please upload your Categoria model

Comment: what is `Categoria`? If that is your model class you need to create a DB entry by calling `Categoria.objects.create( … )`

Comment: sorry i'm not translate from spanish to english ..i edit my question..!!

Comment: The arguments need to be evaluated before the `Category` instantiation, so you're actually passing the string from `request.POST.get('category')` instead of a `Category` instance, hence the error. You can do what you're asking for if `parent` is nullable; save `category` without `parent` set, then set it with `category.parent = category`, and save again. You can't do this in one step, because you're trying to reference a row that does not exist yet.

Comment: post your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change the field name parent to parent_id:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
description = request.POST.get('description')
category = request.POST.get('category')
category = Category(
   name = nombre,
   name = descripcion,
   parent_id = int(category)
)
category.save()
```

**parent -> Should be a Category instance (object)**

**parent_id -> Should be a int (id of the object)**

Good luck.

Comment: yeah.... you really solve my problem thanks... sorry the problem was a simple thing... ..!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the id of the category, not the object.

Try this:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
description = request.POST.get('description')
category_id = request.POST.get('category') 
category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
category = Category(
    name = name,
    name = description,
    parent = category
)
category.save()
```